# Gravitational force in a lever

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

Let's consider a lever with some objects on it. The objects have the same mass.

[image]

We know that an equal gravitational force acts on the objects. Its formula is:

$\bar{F}=m\frac{d\bar{v}}{dt}$

This means that in $a dt$, each object undergoes a dv perpendicular to the ground, according to the formula:

$d\bar{v}=\bar{g}dt$

In $a dt$, the $dv$ caused by the objects in the picture is the same, since $d\bar{v}=\bar{g}dt$ is obviously the same for the three objects.
In addition, every object in the picture produces a 
$d\bar{\omega }=\frac{d\bar{v}}{R}$, but this time $d\bar{\omega }$ depends on the position of the object with respect of the fulcrum.
Why in $a dt$ the objects in A and C produces the same  $d\bar{\omega }$ that the objects in B ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're conflating torque and force and ending up confused, I think.

Assume all three objects have an (individual) mass $m$ and that they are resp. $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ distance from the pivot point.

The total torque $\tau$ about the fulcrum is:

$$\tau=x_1 mg+2x_2 mg+x_3 mg=(x_1+2x_2+x_3)mg$$

Without any opposing torque, the beam will now start rotating clockwise, acc. Newton's 2nd for rotation:

$$\tau=I\ddot{\theta}$$

where $I$ is the inertial moment of the beam plus masses and $\ddot{\theta}$ the angular acceleration of the beam.

Assuming the beam is mass-less, then:

$$I=mx_1^2+2mx_2^2+mx_3^2=m(x_1^2+2x_2^2+x_3^2)$$

In an infinitesimal amount of time $\mathbf{d}t$, each mass will accelerate:

$$\mathbf{d}\omega=\frac{\tau}{I}\mathbf{d}t=\frac{(x_1+2x_2+x_3)mg}{m(x_1^2+2x_2^2+x_3^2)}\mathbf{d}t=\frac{(x_1+2x_2+x_3)g}{(x_1^2+2x_2^2+x_3^2)}\mathbf{d}t$$

The corresponding translational velocity changes $\mathbf{d}v_i$ are:

$$\mathbf{d}v_i=x_i\times \frac{(x_1+2x_2+x_3)g}{(x_1^2+2x_2^2+x_3^2)}\mathbf{d}t$$

Comment: However, my intention was to prove why the two objects in B are equivalent of the ones in A and C, by deriving all the results starting from the force definition

Comment: Why can i replace the objects in A and C with the 2 objects in B ? What physical quantity they change equally in a dt ?

Comment: You can, as long as $\frac{x_A+x_C}{2}=x_C$ and $m_A=m_B=m_C$. The torques are then the same.

Comment: This is very nice. Thanks so much

Comment: Here we don't thank, instead we upvote!

Comment: I'm sorry. I have provided

Comment: Thank you! Glad it helped.

Comment: Do you have telepathic powers? How did you ever figure out what is being asked? :P